# Making progress bar move HTML jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some code that i got online and to make the progress bar move you have to click buttons, but i just want it to move by itself. I want it so it is sort of fast in the start then it gets fast about half way. Here is the code.

http://hastebin.com/ereyoselek.xml
By the way i had to put it into a link because the code tool on here was messing with the code.

Also here is a link to where i got the code
http://www.cssflow.com/snippets/animated-progress-bar

I have tried looking up videos online but they all seem to be different to what i am doing.
Hope you guys can help thanks :)

Comment: which progress? uploading something? downloading?

Comment: Just random. Just progress bar that moves

Comment: If you want to get animated div you also can use jquery http://api.jquery.com/animate/. and you can use .delay(). I think you are pretty new in JS so trust me read the link completly and try yourself. This is the best way to understand and the bes way to learn how to do. If you really dont know how JS(jquery) works you can find the answere of your question in already asked qeustions on stackoverflow. Have a nice day